# Does $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=0$ imply that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x) $ exist?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that there is a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, with $\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$ existing and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=0$. Does this imply that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists?

I think the answer is yes. Here is my reason. When x is sufficiently large, we have $|\frac{d}{dx}f(x)|<\epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ being arbitrarily small. Hence, $|f(x+C)-f(x)|=|\int_x^{x+C}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)dx|\leq\int_x^{x+C}|\frac{d}{dx}f(x)|dx\leq C\epsilon$. If we choose sufficiently large numbers $x_i$, $i=1,2,3,\cdots$, then $\{f(x_i),i=1,2,\cdots\}$ is an Cauchy squence, and thus $f(x_i)$ converges to a point. Since $f(x)$ is contineous, this point is unique.

Am I right? If the answer is yes, does anyone have simpler proof?

Comment: If we further assume the function $f(x)$ is bounded, i.e., $|f(x)|<M$, what's the answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider the function $f(x) = \ln x$.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, OP specified that $f$ is defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$ not just $(0,\infty)$. So, we should use something like $f(x) = \ln(x^2+1)$ as counterexample instead of $\ln(x)$.

Comment: And that is that!  +1

Comment: @JimmyK4542 : We could say $f(x) = \ln(x^2+1)$ to be strictly within OP's context... but this was the correct example to state :) +1

Comment: I prefer $f(x) = x^{1-\epsilon}$ as a counter-example. if when $x \to \infty$, $f'(x) \to 0$ then $f(x) = o(x)$, that's all you can say

Comment: If we further assume the function $f(x)$ is bounded, i.e., $|f(x)|<M$, what's the answer?

Comment: The answer is still no. Consider the function $f(x) = \sin(\ln(x^2+1))$.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your argument, I think, is that the condition $|f(x+C)-f(x)|< C\epsilon$ is not enough to show that the sequence is Cauchy. Take the sequence equivalent to the one Jimmy suggested, that is, $P_n= \Sigma_{k=1}^n 1/k$. Then, for $C=1$, we have that $f(n+1)-f(1)= 1/n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. You need something stronger to guarantee Cauchyness.